# Hide all the html table where there is no result from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make a dropdown menu where the user chooses a letter and then outputs all the names which start with this letter in a table I created.
The names are selected from a database. Now I want this table to be hidden when the user hasn't chosen a letter yet or when there are no results from the database. So I want the table to show up only when there is a result from the database. Here is my code:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Title</title>
  <style>
    table {
      width: 100%;
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    table,
    td,
    th {
      border: 1px solid black;
      padding: 5px;
    }
    th {
      text-align: left;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <?php $con=mysqli_connect( 'localhost', 'root', 'evolvia2016', 'presta_prova'); if (!$con) { die( 'Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con)); } ?>
  <form method="post">
    <select name="users">
      <option value="">Scegliete una lettera:</option>
      <option value="A">A</option>
      <option value="B">B</option>
      <option value="C">C</option>
      <option value="D">D</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go" />
  </form>
  <br>
  <div id="txtHint"><b>Vedi qui i tipi ti marche:</b>
  </div>
  <table id='results'>
    <tr>
      <th>Marca</th>
      <th>Descrizione</th>
    </tr>
    <?php $q=$ _POST[ "users"]; //$sql="SELECT * FROM presta_prova WHERE marca LIKE 'B%' " ; $sql="SELECT * FROM presta_prova WHERE marca LIKE '" . $q . "%' "; $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql); while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { echo "<tr>"; echo
    "<td>" . $row[ "marca"] . "</td>"; echo "<td>" . $row[ "descrizione"] . "</td>"; echo "</tr>"; } echo "</table>"; ?>
  </table>
</body>
<?php mysqli_close($con); ?>

</html>
```

I try to insert a hidden attribute but it doesn't solve the problem. Can someone tell me how to make it hidden for the cases above? Thanks!

Comment: The logic is check your result if the result is empty/not. based on the condition to change the table CSS property as display="none" likewise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the logic

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect( 'localhost', 'root', 'evolvia2016', 'presta_prova'); if (!$con) { die( 'Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con)); } 
$sql= mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM presta_prova WHERE marca LIKE 'B%'") ;
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
$totalRows_results = mysqli_num_rows($sql);     
?>


<?php if($totalRows_results > 0) { ?>

Anything inside here will be visible if the query returns any result
//e.g you may echo out your results here <?php echo $row['column']; ?>


    you can also do your while loop inside here
    <?php do { ?>
    //your repeating region
       <?php echo $row['column']; ?>  //i.e.  <?php echo $row['marca']; ?>
    <?php } while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)); ?>  

<?php } ?>



<?php if($totalRows_results == 0) { ?>

Anything inside here will be visible if the query does not return any result
//e.g you may display an error message here like. sorry no result found

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**This may Help you, Simple Way**

PHP Works only at Page load only, So you need to use Javascript/Jquery to hide the table, otherwise use php mysqli_num_rows() function, the functions returns number of records fetched, if it fetch the rows, generate the table otherwise leave some warning message, I added the sample to your code

```
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>Title</title>
      <style>
        table {
          width: 100%;
          border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        table,
        td,
        th {
          border: 1px solid black;
          padding: 5px;
        }
        th {
          text-align: left;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <?php $con=mysqli_connect( 'localhost', 'root', 'evolvia2016', 'presta_prova'); if (!$con) { die( 'Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con)); } ?>
      <form method="post">
        <select name="users">
          <option value="">Scegliete una lettera:</option>
          <option value="A">A</option>
          <option value="B">B</option>
          <option value="C">C</option>
          <option value="D">D</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go" />
      </form>
      <br>
      <div id="txtHint"><b>Vedi qui i tipi ti marche:</b>
      </div>
        <?php $q=$ _POST[ "users"]; //$sql="SELECT * FROM presta_prova WHERE marca LIKE 'B%' " ; $sql="SELECT * FROM presta_prova WHERE marca LIKE '" . $q . "%' "; 
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)  // if record found, this generate the table
{
echo "<table id='results'>
        <tr>
          <th>Marca</th>
          <th>Descrizione</th>
        </tr>";
 while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { echo "<tr>"; echo
        "<td>" . $row[ "marca"] . "</td>"; echo "<td>" . $row[ "descrizione"] . "</td>"; echo "</tr>"; } echo "</table>";
}
else
  echo "No Output for the Query";
 ?>
    </body>
    <?php mysqli_close($con); ?>
    </html>
```

Comment: Now the output is blank.

Comment: @Doe Check your query, print your query and check that in Phpmyadmin, whether that fetch the data or not